# Convert triangle strips to Octagonal?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, codeblocks

I'm using the gl.h library and it outputs triangle strips. The example shows this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define step 8
#define angle 3.1415926 * 2.f / step

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC*, HGLRC*);
void DisableOpenGL(HWND, HDC, HGLRC);


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    HWND hwnd;
    HDC hDC;
    HGLRC hRC;
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bQuit = FALSE;
    float theta = 0.0f;

    /* register window class */
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "GLSample";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);;


    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 0;

    /* create main window */
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
                          "GLSample",
                          "OpenGL Sample",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          600,
                          600,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    /* enable OpenGL for the window */
    EnableOpenGL(hwnd, &hDC, &hRC);

    /* program main loop */
    while (!bQuit)
    {
        /* check for messages */
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            /* handle or dispatch messages */
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                bQuit = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* OpenGL animation code goes here */

            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glPushMatrix();
            //glRotatef(theta, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

  
                float xPos = 0;
                float yPos = 0;
                float radius = 0.5f;
                float prevX = xPos;
                float prevY = yPos - radius;


            for (int i=0;i<=step;i++)
            {
                float newX =   radius *   sin(angle * i);
                float newY = - radius * cos(angle * i);

                glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                glColor3f(0,0.5f,0);

                glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(prevX , prevY , 0.0f);
                glVertex3f(newX , newY   , 0.0f);



                prevX = newX;
                prevY = newY;


            }

            glEnd();






            glPopMatrix();
            SwapBuffers(hDC);
            theta += 1.0f;
            Sleep (1);
        }
    }

    /* shutdown OpenGL */
    DisableOpenGL(hwnd, hDC, hRC);

    /* destroy the window explicitly */
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            return 0;

        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            switch (wParam)
            {
                case VK_ESCAPE:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    int iFormat;

    /* get the device context (DC) */
    *hDC = GetDC(hwnd);

    /* set the pixel format for the DC */
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
                  PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);

    SetPixelFormat(*hDC, iFormat, &pfd);

    /* create and enable the render context (RC) */
    *hRC = wglCreateContext(*hDC);

    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
}

void DisableOpenGL (HWND hwnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
}
```

```
                float xPos = 0;
                float yPos = 0;
                float radius = 0.5f;
                float prevX = xPos;
                float prevY = yPos - radius;


        for (int i=0;i<=step;i++)
        {
            float newX =   radius *   sin(angle * i);
            float newY = - radius * cos(angle * i);

            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glColor3f(0,0.5f,0);

            glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
            glVertex3f(prevX , prevY , 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(newX , newY   , 0.0f);



            prevX = newX;
            prevY = newY;


        }

        glEnd();
```

[image]

The issue is in the fact that this renders multiple triangle strips. This is a problem for me. My application renders with IDE - code Blocks v17.12 and I need a way to modify the above code so that instead it could look something more like this:

[image]

Comment: What is your question? How to rewrite the second snippet for a `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`? What's your problem with this? Btw. `glBegin()` _in_ the loop but `glEnd()` _after_ looks wrong for me. AFAIR, `glBegin()` and `glEnd()` have to be used pairwise. Maybe, your driver is clever enough to make an implicit `glEnd()` at a repeated `glBegin()`. (All I found in the [doc. of glBegin](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) concerning this is that it's not listed itself in the accepted subset of commands allowed between `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`.)

Comment: I want to create the second pic that exists, the lines of which are also clear. I can not do this. My problem is that everything I do does not show the lines.

Comment: Lines are usually not rendered. (OpenGL is not like the usual 2d graphics APIs concerning this.) However, you can tweak this in various ways. One option could be to render the tristrip twice, the 2nd time with different color and [glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml). For the second pass, you have to switch depth test of, or (probably more robust) to fiddle with [glPolygonOffset()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonOffset.xhtml).

Comment: You also can try to render the wireframe first and then the filled polygon without switching depth test off or fiddling with polygon offset. Due to depth test, the filled polygon shouldn't overwrite the wireframe, and using the same primitive with precise same values, there even may not occur any [depth buffer fighting].(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). I'm not 100 % sure it whether it works this way but it's simple to check out. (It's a while ago that I used OpenGL prior V3+.)

Comment: I tried the method and said I hope I can show the lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the polygon rasterization mode `GL_LINE` to render a wire frame:

```cpp
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
```

```cpp
float xPos = 0.0f;
float yPos = 0.0f;
float radius = 0.5f;
int steps = 8;
```

```cpp
float prevX = xPos;
float prevY = yPos - radius;

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor3f(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);

for (int i=0; i <= step; ++i)
{
    float angle = 3.1415926f * 2.0f * i / step;
    float newX =   radius * sin(angle);
    float newY = - radius * cos(angle);

    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(prevX, prevY, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(newX, newY, 0.0f);

    prevX = newX;
    prevY = newY;
}
glEnd();
```

[image]

Use a `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` [Triangle primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) to simplify your code:

```cpp
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
glColor3f(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);

for (int i=0; i <= step; ++i)
{
    float angle = 3.1415926f * 2.0f * i / step;
    float newX =   radius * sin(angle);
    float newY = - radius * cos(angle);
    glVertex3f(newX, newY, 0.0f);
}
glEnd();
```

[image]

If you want to use a triangle `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, you must change the order of the vertices:

```cpp
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
glColor3f(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);

for (int i=0; i <= step; ++i)
{
    int strip_i = i % 2 == 0 ? i/2 : step - i/2;
    float angle = 3.1415926f * 2.0f * strip_i / step;
    float newX =   radius * sin(angle);
    float newY = - radius * cos(angle);
    glVertex3f(newX, newY, 0.0f);
}
glEnd();
```

[image]

If you want to render the wire frame on top of the polygon, you need to enable the [depth test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) and render the polygon first. Note the default depth test function is `GL_LESS`:

```cpp
for (int pass = 0; pass < 2; ++pass)
{
    if (pass == 0)
    {
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    }

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (int i=0; i <= step; ++i)
    {
        int strip_i = i % 2 == 0 ? i/2 : step - i/2;
        float angle = 3.1415926f * 2.0f * strip_i / step;
        float newX =   radius * sin(angle);
        float newY = - radius * cos(angle);
        glVertex3f(newX, newY, 0.0f);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you have this sample just open in your editor... Could you try to "overlay" a filled polygon with its wireframe by just first rendering with `LINE` (and another color) and then again with `FILL`? (I already spent my vote for motivation.) ;-)

Comment: I was in hope to come around the polygon offset by rendering the wireframe first. (When I did it once in the past, I used the polygon offset but draw the wireframe over the solid. If done in reverse order this might be not necessary, maybe.)

Comment: @Scheff It took a while because the code snippet in my editor is written in Python

Comment: Thanks. Awesome. (I will spend another vote.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Z-fighting shouldn't be a problem here as the primitive type and vertices are the same.